# compiler behavior on curly braces and semicolon if statement

Tags: java, if-statement, curly-braces

I started learning myself *Java fundamentals* a few months ago (at the amateur level familiar with `PHP` for several years).

To practise I use a *OCA Java SE 8 Programmer 1 Study Guide* and an example exam question is given which confuses me about **use of curly braces and semicolons** in `if-statement` and can't find back in *Java documentation*.

I do not understand why answer **E** is allowed and compiles.
I've tried in Netbeans 10 (JDK 11) to evaluate warnings en hints but doesn't lead me to understand fundament.
Also trying multiple combinations that will compile ( only warning of `Empty statement`).
`if (true) ; {;;{}{}{}} ;;;;;;;;`
`if (true) ;;{}{{}{}{}}; {;;{}{}{}} ;;;;;;;;`
`if (true) ;;{}{{}{}{}}; {;;{}{}{}}`

**Question:Which of the following statements will not compile?**
**A.** `if (true) ;`
**B.** `if (true) {}`
**C.** `if (true) {;}`
**D.** `if (true) {;;}`
**E.** `if (true) ; {} ;`
**F.** `All statements will compile`*(=correct answer)*

Please help!
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I do not understand why answer `E` is allowed and compiles.

In Java, a `;` can either be a statement terminator or an empty statement, depending on the context.

Here's is how the (valid) Java code in option `E` is parsed:

```
  if (true) // <-- "if" and its condition
  ;         // an empty statement which is the "then" part of the "if"
  {}        // an (empty) block statement
  ;         // an empty statement
```

The first two lines are the complete `if` statement.  The third and fourth lines are statements following the `if` statement.

Comment: OK, I get it. The third en fourth line has nothing to do with the if-statement. I tried in IDE en third and fourth lines compiles even without first two lines.

Answer (score 0):

Answer **E** will compile because the symbol `;` is allowed statement in java. In this case `if` statement just has empty body and make no sense, but it's valid.

From [java specification 14.6. The Empty Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6):

> An empty statement does nothing.
>   EmptyStatement:
>       `;`
>
> Execution of an empty statement always completes normally.

---

The `{}` is just an empty block of code that is allowed in java also.

See [java spec 14.2. Blocks](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-Block)